# Update database value from 0 to 1 based on a selected option after form send

Tags: php, mysql

my problem seems simple but I do not know much about PHP.

I have two tables:

Table 1: ** certificates ** / Table2: ** keys **

They don't have the same order or amount of columns. Table2 has predeterminated values while table1 is clean, receiving data inserted by the user.

The user uses a form to insert data into table1. In this form, there's a select populated with data from table2.

The select options are keys, like those:

1112, 1113, 1114, etc.

What I need is when the user insert one of the keys in table1, the status of the key in table2 is updated from 0 to 1. (so the key will not be shown in the select).

**Here's the code that inserts the data into table1**

```
<?php
if ($registro != "") {
    include("conexao-certificado.php");
    $conexao = @mysql_connect($host, $user, $pass)
        or die("Cadastro");
    $query = "INSERT INTO certificados VALUES ('$id','$registro','$aluno','$professor','$escola','$publicado_por','$registrado_por','$ano','$curso','$cpf','$grade', now() );";
    mysql_query($query, $conexao);
    $url = basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
    echo "<script>window.location='$url'</script>";
} else {

}

?>
```

**And here's the code that populates the select:**

```
<?php
include("conexao-certificado.php");
$conexao = @mysql_connect($host, $user, $pass);
if (!$conexao)
    die("Nao foi possivel conectar no servidor MySQL. Erro: " . mysql_error());
mysql_select_db($db) or die("Nao foi possivel usar o banco de dados. Erro: " .
        mysql_error());
$palavra = str_replace(" ", "%", $HTTP_POST_VARS[palavra]);
$qr = "SELECT idchave FROM chaves WHERE (publicado_por LIKE '%" . $_SESSION['nome'] . "%" . $_SESSION['sobrenome'] . "%' AND status LIKE '0' )  ORDER BY idchave ASC;";
$sql = mysql_query($qr);

?>
<select name="registro" id="registro">
    <?php
    echo '<option value="">Selecione a chave</option>';
    while ($r = mysql_fetch_array($sql)) {
        echo '<option value="' . $r['idchave'] . '">' . $r['idchave'] . '</option>';
    }

    ?>
</select>
```

I tried puting this after the INSERT, but it only works if i specifie the key like "idchave=1112".

```
$atualiza = "UPDATE chaves SET status=1 WHERE idchave=$registro;";
mysql_select_db($db);
mysql_query($query,$conexao);
mysql_query($atualiza,$conexao);
```

I found a solution. So here's what I did.
First a created a column in table1 with status always being 1 while on table2 the status are always 0.

After that I just added a INNER JOIN in my code.

Here's the code:

```
$atualiza = "UPDATE chaves c1
INNER JOIN certificados c2 ON c1.registro = c2.registro
SET c1.status = c2.status;";
mysql_query($atualiza,$conexao);
```

Thank you for all the help.

Comment: FYI, [you shouldn't use `mysql_*` functions in new code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [red box](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) will help you decide which one is best for you.

Comment: Your script is at risk of [SQL Injection Attack](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) Have a look at what happened to [Little Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com/) Even [if you are escaping inputs, its not safe!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string) Use [prepared parameterized statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php).

Comment: Don't use the error suppression operator (@) as it hides error messages that may be helpful in debugging your code. You should also always write your code so it does not generate any PHP errors including notices.

Comment: Please do not use tags that do not apply to your question.

Comment: At [so] you are expected to try to **write the code yourself**. After **[doing more research](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592)** if you have a problem you can **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and providing a [**Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). I suggest reading [ask] a good question and [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/). Also, be sure to take the [tour] and read **[this](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/347937/)**.

Answer (score 0):

To achieve your goal,

after your insert query on table1,
create an update query for your table2
that will update the status to 1, 
after updating your table2,

add a condition on your dropdown selection query, to display only fields with status0 on your table2,

so that it wont be displayed on the selection anymore

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I already have a condition that only display the fields with 0. I found a solution using INNER JOIN and edited the question explaining what I did.